# How can I specify commits for pull request on Bitbucket?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket

I have a mercurial repository on Bitbucket that is forked from another repo. I made several commits to my fork and now want to make pull-request to the main repo.
But I want to include in pull-request only last 2 commits, not all that I have done as Bitbucket offer. Is it possible to do pull-request through Bitbaket, which includes only those commits that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a pull or push, you can specify a revision, but it necessarily comes with all its ancestors that are not on the repo. If you planned it correctly, and the last two commits are the sole constituents of a separate branch, started from the main trunk, yes, only those 2 commits should be pulled. But from your question, I doubt this is the case.

In Bitbucket, it seems to be possible to request a pull on a branch. So my suggestion is to create another branch, started from the main trunk, and replicate your last 2 commits. There are many ways to do that, but the fastest, *albeit not recommended in a normal workflow, but considering your current state*, is to graft the 2 commits on that new branch.

```
hg update default
hg branch <new feature branch>
hg graft -r <commit 1>
hg graft -r <commit 2>
```

Then, request a pull on `<new feature branch>`.